# How can I make a loop with changing random numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, random, while-loop

I want to make a game that will generate multipication equations. I want to make it that you will get a simple multipication equation (ex: 5*6) and when you answer it, the program will tell you if you are correct, and then will go to the next random equation.
I know how to make it with a lot of different random numbers, but this will make the code very long and not ellegant.
I need a way to generate two different random numbers every time, without having to make a data base of let's say 20 different random numbers. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks!

This is the code I've wrote so far:

```
import random
import sys
import os

random_num1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
random_num2 = random.randrange(1, 10)

print(random_num1, 'X', random_num2, '=', )

def multiplication(random_num1, random_num2):
    sumNum = random_num1 * random_num2
    return sumNum

one = input()

if(int(one) == multiplication(random_num1, random_num2)):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

Comment: "I need a way to generate two different random numbers every time" I think you're saying that you don't want the program to generate a pair of numbers that it has already generated (in this run of the program). Is that correct? If that's the case, a better design is to allow repeats if the user got the wrong answer last time.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your code into a while loop that never ends using `while True:` (and don't forget to move everything inside by one tab to the right).

It's advisable to move `def multiplication` out of the `while` loop though.

Comment: Thank you very much! and if I want to run it specificlly for 10 times, how do i do that?

Comment: Then track with a counter. Set `counter = 0` then do the `while` loop like this. `while counter < 10:` then inside `while` loop increase the `counter` like this `counter += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do it with a function and a while loop. Let's say, you want to play 10 times and want the score at the end.

```
def multiplication(random_num1, random_num2):
    sumNum = random_num1 * random_num2
    # Indentation fixed
    return sumNum

def play() : 
    random_num1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
    random_num2 = random.randrange(1, 10)

    print(random_num1, 'X', random_num2, '=', )

    one = input()

    if(int(one) == multiplication(random_num1, random_num2)):
       return 1
    else:
       return 0

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    number_of_play = 10
    cpt = 0
    result = 0
    while cpt < number_of_play :
        cpt+=1
        cpt += play()
    print "Wow you perform {} out of {}".format(result, number_of_play)
```

Comment: Thanks! but I didnt understand a lot of the code... the part of the "def play" and the part of the "if" statement at the end. could you explain it for me?

Comment: def play() will create the function who corresponds to juste one play : print two numbers, ask for the restult and check if the user won. We will use this function in the while loop and call it ten times. We get the result of each try in "result". The last if is a trick in python, you can learn more about that here : http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a simple example made by me (EDITED with "try" statement):

```
from random import randint

while 1:
    numA = randint(0,9)
    numB = randint(0,9)
    result = numA * numB

    print("\nFirst number:", numA)
    print("Second number:", numB)

    while 1: 
        try: 
            userResult = int(input("Insert your multiplication result: ")) 
            break
        except: 
            print("Error! The given digit is not a number. Retry :")

    if userResult == result:
        print("Bravo! That's right!")
    else:
        print("Damn! That's wrong!")
```

I've tried to be as clear as possible. I hope it was useful for you.

Comment: I'ts clear, thank you. But now I've got a different problem, if the user writes anything that is not a number, then it comes out as an error. I think its because the "int" before the input, it happend in my code aswell. Do you know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sure... here it is a simple way to check what the user digit.

Comment: while 1:
  try:
   userResult = int(input("Insert your multiplication result: "))
   break #if "int()" does not gives error, break will be executed 
  except:
   print("Error! The given digit is not a number. Retry :)")

Comment: "try" statement catch an error and instead of closing the program, it will execute what is inside "except" statement (in this case it will print a line). All there lines must be put inside an infinite loop (while 1), and you will "break" the loop only when user added a number

Comment: It did now work out for me... any chance you can write the code like it's in python?

Comment: I edited my post so you can have a full python code view